# Counts on spanning tree with G and its complement graph G'

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I got a really hard problem that is there any graphs G(G is not a self-complementary graph) that has the same count of spanning tree with its complement tree G'?

I tried multiple methods to get the result but got nothing.

I tried to use Java to generate all graphs and get its complement graph and compare their counts of spanning trees. It is aged so that I stopped it when generating order-10 graphs. That is, now I know it doesn't exist with graphs that have less than 10 vertices.
I tried to use the degree matrix of G to show if there can or cannot be the same co-factor with a graphic matrix with its complement graph's matrix, but as the calculate was based on the matrixes, I didn't get a reasonable result that can prove anything.
Thus, are there any graphs that have the same count of spanning tree with its complement graph and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are such graphs. Indeed, there are infinitely many non self-complementary graphs that have the same [Tutte polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial) as their complement; see [this mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132728/tutte-polynomials-graph-complements-and-degree-sequences). Since the Tutte polynomial encodes the number of spanning forests of a graph (i.e. if $T_G$ is the Tutte polynomial of $G$, $T_G(1,1)$ is the number of spanning forests), this answers your question affirmatively.

Well, except you were asking about *spanning trees* and I'm talking about *spanning forests*. But at a cursory glance it seems that the construction cited in the link gives connected graphs with connected complements, in which case the two notions are the same.